# elastic search, dealing with many sub aggs who can be null

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to query elastic to get aggs with sub aggs.

My working* query :

```
  {
    "_source" : false,
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "level1" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "level1",
                "size" : 10
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "level2" : {
                    "terms" : {
                        "field" : "level2",
                        "size" : 10
                    },
                    "aggs" : {
                        "level3" : {
                            "terms" : {
                                "field" : "level3",
                                "size" : 10
                            },
                            "aggs" : {
                                "level4" : {
                                    "terms" : {
                                        "field" : "level4"",
                                        "size" : 10
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

This work perfectly where each "levelX" is filled in elastic.
BUT sometimes the value of a "levelX" can be null ( data not informed yet for example) but the sub level are not null and i need to get them all, but elastic return aggs only when "levelX" is not null.

Example of data injected in elastic :

```
  [
    { "level1" : "level1" ,  "level2" : null , "level3" : "level3" , "level4" : "level4 a" },
    { "level1" : "level1" ,  "level2" : null , "level3" : "level3" , "level4" : "level4 b" } 
 ]
```

What i want :

```
"aggregations": {
    "level1": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "level1",
                "doc_count": 2,
                "level2": {
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "key": "", // "" or null or anythink
                            "doc_count": 2,
                            "level3": {
                                "buckets": [
                                    {
                                        "key": "level3",
                                        "doc_count": 2,
                                        "level4": {
                                            "buckets": [
                                               {  "key": "level4 a", "doc_count": 1 },
                                               {  "key": "level4 a", "doc_count": 1 }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
]}}]}}]}}
```

What i get :

```
"aggregations": {
    "level1": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "level1",
                "doc_count": 2,
                "level2": {
                    "buckets": []
}}]}}]}}
```

How can i do that or what is the type of this kind of query ?

EDIT 1 : the "missing" option is maybe what i need but i can have up to 10 sub levels, putting it in all the levels or making a "missing_levelX" is maybe not the best solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your mapping, you could specify the [`null_value` property](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#string) for your `string` fields.

```
{
  "your_type": {
    "properties": {
      "level1": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "null_value": "<null>",            <--- pick whatever makes sense for you
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't specify `null_value` and your field has a null value, ES will ignore the field, whereas if you specify `null_value` it will store the specified value instead.

Comment: ok thank you.
I will try this solution as soon as i can make the mapping be edited